# C# Console CGI graphics using too much memory

Tags: c#, memory, console, drawing

I'm experimenting with cgi in c#. I have made an app where you can move a square (with arrows) inside a rectangle that can be resized. I'm painting rectangles over one to resize it. I use collision class to restrict movement past edges.

Everything seems fine, however I'am concerned about it's memory usage. When I start increasing it's size, memory consuption goes up and triggers GC.

Could someone help me find this leak? Am I doing something wrong that spikes up the usage? Do I use buffer the wrong way?

EDIT:: Actually, I found out what was causing that memory usage it was this line of code. After commenting out this block of code, my program used only 16MB instead of 2GB.

```
   if (player.rectHeight >= tempWidth)
            {
                Program.bufferedGraphics = context.Allocate(Program.graphics, 
    new Rectangle(0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(player.rectWidth) + 100,
                Convert.ToInt32(player.rectHeight) + 100));
            }
```

Thanks for your time.

The code

```
class Program
{

    static Graphics graphics;
    static BufferedGraphics bufferedGraphics;
    static Player player;
    static Collision collision;
    static Utility utility;
    static SByte value = 0;
    static float tempWidth = 500;
    static void Main()
    {
        Program.player = new Player();
        Program.utility = new Utility();
        Program.collision = new Collision();
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        Program.graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(GetDC(process.MainWindowHandle));
        BufferedGraphicsContext context = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
        context.MaximumBuffer = new Size(Console.WindowWidth, Console.WindowHeight);
        Program.bufferedGraphics = context.Allocate(Program.graphics, new Rectangle(0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(player.rectWidth), 
            Convert.ToInt32(player.rectHeight)));


        while (true)
        {
            collision.worldEdges = new Collision.WorldEdges()
            {
                rightBorder = Convert.ToInt32(player.rectWidth),
                leftBorder = 0,
                topBorder = 0,
                bottomBorder = Convert.ToInt32(player.rectHeight),
            };
            if (player.rectHeight >= tempWidth)
            {
                Program.bufferedGraphics = context.Allocate(Program.graphics, new Rectangle(0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(player.rectWidth) + 100,
                Convert.ToInt32(player.rectHeight) + 100));
            }
            //Debug.Print(Convert.ToString(player.rectHeight));
            // Debug.Print(Convert.ToString(player.x));
            //Debug.Print(Convert.ToString(player.x- collision.worldEdges.rightBorder));
            if (player.y > collision.worldEdges.bottomBorder-19.7f) // if on the edge, clamp its movement
            {
                player.y = collision.worldEdges.bottomBorder-19.8f;


            }
            if (player.x > collision.worldEdges.rightBorder - 19.7)
            {
                player.x = collision.worldEdges.rightBorder - 19.8f;
            }
            else
            {
                Program.player.DoMove();
            }
            Program.player.ResizeScreen(out value); //check whether resize the rectangle

            if (value ==1) //g decrease size
            {
                bufferedGraphics.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, 
                    Convert.ToInt32(player.rectWidth), Convert.ToInt32(player.rectHeight));
                player.rectHeight -= 0.08f;
                player.rectWidth -=  0.08f;
                tempWidth = player.rectWidth;
            }
            if (value == -1) //h increase size
            {
                bufferedGraphics.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, 
                    Convert.ToInt32(player.rectWidth), Convert.ToInt32(player.rectHeight));
                player.rectHeight += 0.08f;
                player.rectWidth +=  0.08f;
                //Program.bufferedGraphics = context.Allocate(Program.graphics, new Rectangle(0, 0, 320,200));
                bufferedGraphics.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, 0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(player.rectWidth),
            Convert.ToInt32(player.rectHeight));
                tempWidth = player.rectWidth;
            }
            else
            {
                bufferedGraphics.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, 0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(player.rectWidth),
         Convert.ToInt32(player.rectHeight));
            }
            Program.player.DrawPlayer(Program.bufferedGraphics.Graphics, Brushes.Blue); //draw player controlled cube
            Program.bufferedGraphics.Render(Program.graphics); //finally render on screen

        }
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern short GetKeyState(int nVirtKey);
}
class Player //detect input and set player size and it's movement
{
    const int LEFT = 0x25;
    const int UP = 0x26;
    const int RIGHT = 0x27;
    const int DOWN = 0x28;
    const int G = 0x47;
    public float rectWidth = 200, rectHeight = 200;
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public Player()
    {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }
    public void DoMove()
    {

        if ((GetKeyState(LEFT) | 0x8000) > 0 && this.x < rectWidth-10)
        {
            this.x += 0.1f;
        }
        if ((GetKeyState(RIGHT) | 0x8000) > 0 && this.x > 0)
        {
            this.x -= 0.1f;
        }
        if ((GetKeyState(UP) | 0x8000) > 0 )
        {
            this.y += 0.1f;
        }
        if ((GetKeyState(DOWN) | 0x8000) > 0 && this.y > 0)
        {
            this.y -= 0.1f;
        }
    }
    public void DrawPlayer(Graphics g, Brush color)
    {
        g.FillRectangle(color, this.x , this.y , 20, 20);
    }
    public void  ResizeScreen(out SByte value)
    {
        if ((GetKeyState(G) | 0x8000) < 0)
        {
            value = 1;
        }
        else if ((GetKeyState(0x48) | 0x8000) < 0)
        {
            value = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            value = 0;
        }
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern short GetKeyState(int nVirtKey);

}
class Collision //used for colliding with other objects and world boundaries
{
    public struct WorldEdges
    {
        public int leftBorder;
        public int rightBorder;
        public int topBorder;
        public int bottomBorder;
    }
     public WorldEdges worldEdges;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no surprise that memory consumption increases and the GC gets involved. You have an infinite loop that continually allocates a large buffer (your `bufferedGraphics`), uses it, and then just leaves it hanging. Not only are you consuming memory like crazy, you're failing to dispose a disposable object.

The `BufferedGraphics` class implements the [IDisposable interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx), which means you're supposed to call the `Dispose` method when you're done using it. Doing so quite likely will relieve a lot of the memory pressure. It won't eliminate the memory pressure, but should relieve it a bit.

You might also want to look into the possibility of allocating that `bufferedGraphics` object just once, and re-using it. I'm not familiar enough with `BufferedGraphics`, so I can't say whether that's reasonable. But if you can do it, it should go a long way to reduce the impact of GC on your program.

Finally, do you really need this to run full speed in a `while (true)` loop? If you can do this on a timer, say once every 20 or 50 milliseconds, you'll reduce the load on the CPU and on memory.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I will definitely update my code.

Comment: I edited my question to highlight cause of that leak.